# Tabelas não são criadas automaticamente pelo Hibernate no MySQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

O Hibernate não consegue criar a tabela no banco já criado (drogaria_teste). Segue abaixo código.

Hibernate.cfg.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Configurações de Conexão com o Banco de Dados -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/drogaria_teste?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">q1w2e3r4</property>

        <!-- Pool de Conexões -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>

        <!-- Gerenciamento do Contexto das Sessões -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Cache de Segundo Nível -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Mostra as SQLs Geradas -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Cria as tabelas do banco de dados -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Mapeamento das Entidades -->
        <mapping class="br.alois.drogaria.domain.Estado" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Agora a classe Estado.java

```
package br.alois.drogaria.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "estado")
public class Estado extends GenericDomain {

    @Column(length = 2, nullable = false)
    private String sigla;

    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    // getters e setters

}
```

O arquivo POM:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.alois.drogaria</groupId>
<artifactId>Drogaria</artifactId>
<version>0.5 teste</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<!-- Codificação dos Caracteres -->
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<!-- Parâmetros de Execução -->
<build>
    <!-- Nome do projeto empacotado -->
    <finalName>Drogaria</finalName>

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <plugins>
        <!-- Compilador -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- Dependências -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- Hibernate Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Conector MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

O HibernateUtil :

```
package br.alois.drogaria.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory fabricaDeSessoes = criarFabricaDeSessoes();

    public static SessionFactory getFabricaDeSessoes() {
        return fabricaDeSessoes;
    }

    private static SessionFactory criarFabricaDeSessoes() {
        try {
            Configuration configuracao = new Configuration().configure();

            ServiceRegistry registro = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuracao.getProperties())
                    .build();

            SessionFactory fabrica = configuracao.buildSessionFactory(registro);

            return fabrica;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("A fábrica de sessões não pode ser criada." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Aqui a classe para testar a criação da tabela:

```
package br.alois.drogaria.util;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.junit.Test;

public class HibernateUtilTest {
    @Test
    public void conectar(){
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getFabricaDeSessoes().openSession();
        sessao.close();
        HibernateUtil.getFabricaDeSessoes().close();
    }
}
```

Abaixo o log do console do TomCat 9:

```
ago 16, 2016 8:54:59 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.2.Final}
ago 16, 2016 8:54:59 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
ago 16, 2016 8:54:59 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
ago 16, 2016 8:55:00 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
ago 16, 2016 8:55:00 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
ago 16, 2016 8:55:00 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/drogaria_teste?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC]
ago 16, 2016 8:55:00 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
ago 16, 2016 8:55:00 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
ago 16, 2016 8:55:00 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Tue Aug 16 08:55:00 GMT-03:00 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
ago 16, 2016 8:55:01 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
ago 16, 2016 8:55:01 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@13187b0'
ago 16, 2016 8:55:02 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/drogaria_teste?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC]
```

O que será que está faltando ou que está errado ?

Comment: Não tenho certeza mas acredito que o Hibernate só vai criar as tabelas quando você fizer alguma de query  tipo: `select e from Estado`

Comment: Tá mas isso aparece no log do TomCat. O que faz ciar as tabelas está no hibernate com !-- Cria as tabelas do banco de dados -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
. Agora porque não cria? Queria saber.

Answer (score 1):

acho que lá no persistence.xml onde tem:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

troca por:

```
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado por ajudar Lindemberg Barbosa.

Consegui resolver na linha retirando a argumento registro da linha:

```
SessionFactory fabrica = configuracao.buildSessionFactory(registro);
```

Assim ele procurou pelo `Hibernate.cfg.xml`. Nisso ele me mostrou um conceito que não conhecia que foi o **Hibernate_sequence**. O hibernate criou uma tabela que orienta a uma outra tabela, no caso de herança, qual era o próximo id. Resolvido.

Comment: Consegui resolver na linha retirando a argumento registro da linha: SessionFactory fabrica = configuracao.buildSessionFactory(registro); A solução acima funcionou pra mim também. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Valeu pela dica! retirar o registro resolveu meu problema.